# trying to make an application can attach and detach a tab from window by drag and drop like google chrome web browser?

Tags: winapi, tabs, window

I'd like to make an application which user can drag and drop tab to make a new window contains

a tab control user holds. What i am looking for is the exact same functionality of Google

Chrome browser for window and Internet explorer 9. Both Applications create a new window if

if user drags and drop a tab out of original window. and vice versa.

How do i do this? Any advice or sample code will be appreciated

Comment: The Chromium Project is open source... Start [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/).

Comment: @Cody Thanks I didn't know chrome browser is open sourced. I thought it's google's proprietary browser But i don't get which part of source should be looked into. I think it's a quiet huge project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a simple task, but if you work through it bit by bit...

Most tab controls will allow you to detect mousedown (and maybe even drag) and when the cursor is moved away from the tab row, you create a new window with a single tab (and maybe a frame depending on what you want).
When they drop, show the rest of the frame as required.

As for moving the content, this depends on your application layout but it can be as simple as changing the container of a control (`SetParent()`) or the destination of a render.

You can also just drag an "image" of the tab and only create the window when they drop.

Getting any more detail than this is going to be preety much impossible without specifics (and you actually accept an answer).

Comment: thanks for your advice. i am afraid i can not get any event drag and drop event of tab if pointer is going out of application window. if i can tell the mouse point of drop  occured is in or out of main application i can handle with that

Comment: You can't use the normal drag/drop functionality as it is limited to the mouse down window, but you can have your own "tab" window that you mosuedown and move as required.